# What does "We'll just pass him there" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The following text is from the Black Sabbath song "Ironman":

> I am iron man
>   Has he lost his mind?
>   Can he see or is he blind?
>   Can he walk at all,
>   Or if he moves will he fall?
>   Is he alive or dead?
>   Has he thoughts within his head?
>   **We'll just pass him there**
>   Why should we even care?

What does "We'll just pass him there" mean? Is it slang or not?

It certainly sounds like it.

Comment: What do you mean by "slug"? Not the mollusks that destroy my lettuce, probably? But on a more serious note: please elaborate in your question, we need context. Where did you find the quote? Also, it's actually a good idea to put the question in the text, not only in the heading.

Comment: hahaha! Sorry about that, I meant slang. I also made the addition that you suggested.

Comment: It could mean many things. What is the context— who is passing and who is being passed? Which meaning of *pass* is intended, and is it physical or metaphorical/conceptual? Where is "there"?

Comment: Well its part of some lyrics, thus the context is not very specific.

Comment: Here are the lyrics: http://www.lyricsfreak.com/b/black+sabbath/iron+man_20019426.html :D

Comment: I just edited your post to include the text snippet you are asking about. This makes the question easier to read...

Comment: @Fokos Song lyrics, like poetry, are subject to interpretation, and unless the writer has explicitly stated elsewhere what he or she means by a particular line, it is ultimately a matter of opinion.

Comment: @choster yes I know, that is why I said in previous comment that the context won't help much. The question was edited by the way, and lyrics and the song were added Stephie. I just believed that it could be explained without the context.

Comment: I'm going to vote to leave it open, as I interpret the question to be not just about the meaning (which is opinion based), but whether "We'll just pass him there" is standard English or slang. The extra context does help, although the source of the question being song lyrics will cause some folks to vote to close the question. It's tricky to talk about the meaning of lyrics without it becoming a discussion of opinions, but I think there is something to be said based just on the grammar here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the context of the song, it appears to mean, "We'll just walk past him as he stands there."

Comment: Would you consider it slang or a poetic usage? I would probably say "We'll just pass him by - why should we care?".

Comment: I'd call it 'what the heck am I going to get to rhyme with care?' ;)

Comment: I'd consider it poetic, not slang, personally.